# I can't purchase my custom product type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a plugin for custom product type. Here's my class that is being registered on `plugins_loaded` hook:

```
        class WC_Product_Subscription extends WC_Product {

            public function __construct( $product ) {
                $this->product_type = 'subscription';
                $this->purchasable = true;
                $this->downloadable = false;
                $this->virtual = true;
                $this->sold_individually = true;
                $this->manage_stock = false;
                $this->supports[]   = 'ajax_add_to_cart';
                parent::__construct( $product );
            }

            public function is_purchasable() {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

The problem is that I cannot see "Add to Cart" button on the product page which means my product cannot be purchased. I tried adding

```
            public function add_to_cart_url() {
                return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $this->get_id() ), $this );
            }

            public function add_to_cart_text() {
                $text = $this->is_purchasable() && $this->is_in_stock() ? __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) : __( 'Read more', 'woocommerce' );
                return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', $text, $this );
            }
```

to the class but without success. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there are some missing steps to make your custom product type work.

Try the steps below:

#1. Make sure that your plugin is active.

#2. Make sure the product is in stock and has a price set. WooCommerce checks both of these conditions before displaying the `Add to Cart` button.

#3. Check if the custom product type is registered correctly. Use the following code to check:

```
add_action( 'init', 'check_registered_product_types' );
function check_registered_product_types() {
    $product_types = wc_get_product_types();
    var_dump( $product_types );
}
```

#4. Make sure that the WooCommerce product type is supported. Use the following code to check:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'custom_product_type_selector' );
function custom_product_type_selector( $product_types ) {
    var_dump( $product_types );
    return $product_types;
}
```

#5. Make sure that the product class is correctly loaded. Use the following code to check:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'check_product_class' );
function check_product_class() {
    $product_class = 'WC_Product_Subscription';
    var_dump( class_exists( $product_class ) );
}
```

#6. Ensure you have a product template for your custom product type in your theme's WooCommerce folder (e.g. `single-product-subscription.php`).

#7. If everything else seems to be working, you might have to override the WooCommerce templates to display the `Add to Cart` button.

**Edit:**

You can create a template in your plugin directory by using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'wc_subscription_template', 10, 3 );
function wc_subscription_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
    if ( 'single-product-subscription.php' === $template_name ) {
        $template = untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '/templates/single-product-subscription.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This will tell WooCommerce to use your custom `template` in the templates folder within your plugin directory. Make sure you put the code in a file that is included in your plugin, so it will run when the plugin is activated.

Comment: Everything you said to check is correct. The only thing I don't have is a product template for my custom product type but I'm aware I don't know how to create it. How do I create the template within my plugin directory and instruct woocommerce to use it? Because if I create it inside the woocommerce plugin folder I will need to make the customer upload the file inside their woocommerce plugin too, which is not really proffesional.

Comment: I actually ended up with this code: https://i.imgur.com/etRw5QR.png But the strange thing is only the add to cart where you can select quantity is working. The simple "Add to Cart" button which is adding the product to the cart once is not working. Any idea why?

Comment: @howtogeek24 I have edited the post to include information on how to create a template in the plugin directory.